# How to Apply css to webbrowser.documentText and print the html with the applied css?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, webbrowser-control

I have a asp.net mvc web app that has a controller which has an action that returns html to a windows forms client.

The html that is returned gets printed.
This works perfectly and the html looks like the following:

[image]

NOTE that the html is always diffirent.

I designed the html with the help of bootstrap and some other custom css (including inline styles).

As shown above there are stylsheets being linked in to the html.
I haven't been able to figure out how to apply this css to the webBrowser.DocumentText.

With the help of google I found that I have to find the file and link it from there and here is my attempt:

```
    private void PrintDocument(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var document = ((WebBrowser) sender);
        string content = document.DocumentText;

        char separator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        string startupPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string[] pathItems = startupPath.Split(separator);
        string projectPath = string.Join(separator.ToString(),
            pathItems.Take(pathItems.Length - 4));

       string file = Path.Combine(projectPath, "\\IautmationWeb\\Content\\bootstrapSmall.css");

   content = content.Replace("<link href='/Content/bootstrapSmall.css' rel=stylesheet'/>", "<link href='" + projectPath + file + "'rel='stylesheet'/>");

       document.DocumentText = content;

        // add css ... how?
        // print...implemented

        for (int i = 0; i < copies; i++)
        {
            document.Print();
        }

        ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
    }
```

This doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

after some info from @Peter B I tried:

```
     content = content.Replace("href='/Content/bootstrapSmall.css'", "href='" + file + "'");

     document.DocumentText = content;
```

But the replace method is still not doing what I want it to do:

[image]

EDIT:

Thanks to @Peter B

I managed to navigate to the files.

```
        string file = Path.Combine(projectPath, "\\IautmationWeb\\Content\\bootstrapSmall.css");
        string fileTwo = Path.Combine(projectPath, "\\IautmationWeb\\Content\\Automation.css");
        string fileThree = Path.Combine(projectPath, "\\IautmationWeb\\Content\\octicons.css");

        content = content.Replace("href=\"/Content/bootstrapSmall.css\"", "href='" + projectPath +  file + "'");

        content = content.Replace("href=\"/Content/Automation.css\"", "href='" + projectPath + fileTwo + "'");

        content = content.Replace("href=\"/Content/octicons.css\"", "href='" + projectPath + fileThree + "'");

        document.DocumentText = content;
```

how the html looks now:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `rel = 'stylesheet` is correct? It is used twice in the `Replace` call, but in the image it looks different. It might help if you try to find the `href` part and replace it, instead of trying to replace the entire `<link` tag. And last but certainly not least, `file` already contains `projectPath` but you also add it to `file` (once again) in the `Replace` call.

Comment: @PeterB Please check edits. The problem remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to get the quotes wrong, a `'` is not the same as a `"`.

Try this:

```
content = content.Replace("href=\"/Content/bootstrapSmall.css\"", "href='" + file + "'");
```

For the 2nd parameter it doesn't really matter which quotes you use, but for the 1st parameter it does.

Comment: The answer to the question is somwhat correct but the style is still not getting applied. I am printing this to a pdf and the pdf does not look like it is suppse to. An edit to  your anser is that I need to incude the projectPath, it is not included in "file"

Comment: as an extra note, this is a general issue when printing and is not only a problem when prining in pdf format.

Comment: After a few attempts I was forced to solve the print issue with javascipt print function and open  a browser from the forms client to a url with data. Thanks for this, cheers!